# $_POST['val'] = 0 when ajax is not submitted

Tags: php

I don't know why but in a PHP script the variable value is 0 when the post is not submitted to the page...

```
$use = isset( $_POST['use'] ) ? (int) $_POST['use'] : '';
```

No Ajax right now but the following if is always true:

```
// $use must be '' and '' != 0 or 1 right?
if ($use == 0 || $use == 1)
```

Isn't this the correct way of doing it? Why is the code between that if executing?

Comment: You're confusing `isset()` with `empty()`. `""` will pass `isset()`, then your `(int)` will cast it to an `int`, resulting in a value of `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if ($use === 0 || $use === 1)`

Will check the typing of the variable as well

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

With the loose comparison in this instance `0` can be false and `''` can also be seen as false, and thus performing `if('' == 0)` is true

Comment: Right! I forgot that. Thanks!

Comment: There's an additional problem here. The cast in the first line means that a value of `''` will be cast to `0`.